# Query is empty, why?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $_SETTINGS = $GLOBALS["_SETTINGS"];
    $trigger = $_SETTINGS->fields->trigger->value;
    echo $trigger . " = " . $_GET[$trigger] . "</br>";
    $townQry = "SELECT * FROM towns WHERE id = '" . $_GET[$trigger] . "'";
    echo $townQry . "</br>";
    $result = mysql_query($cityQry) or die('Could not retreive towns: ' . mysql_error());

    while ($town = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $town["town_name"];
    }
?>
```

This is what it is echoing out:

```
town_id = 2
SELECT * FROM towns WHERE id = '2'
Could not retreive towns: Query was empty
```

Isn't the SQL valid...!?

Comment: Are you succesfully connected to the database?

Comment: Your variable is `$townQry`, not `$cityQry`.  You must at a minimum call `mysql_real_escape_string()` on `$_GET[$trigger]`.  This is wide open to SQL injection.

Comment: Yeah, that all happens elsewhere. You got it Mike. Create an answer.

Comment: Please [read this carefully](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) and consider using an API supporting prepared statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `$cityQry` in your query, but the query is in `$townQry`.

```
$result = mysql_query($townQry) or die('Could not retreive towns: ' . mysql_error());
```

**Additional**

Your query is wide open to sql injection, I'd advice you to Google prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the query:

```
mysql_query($cityQry)
```

But your query variable is named `$townQuery`.

It should be:

```
mysql_query($townQuery)
```